# Markers of the overlay items stay invisible on MapView

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview, google-api

I am trying to add an overlay to the map view as it is described [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html).
Everything works as expected (even onTap event is fired) except the fact that markers remain invisible.
I've modified an `onTap` method adding the line

```
dialog.setIcon(item.getMarker(0));
```

Now markers become visible after taping any item (i have two items in the overlay and I use the same drawable as a marker for both).
When I turn the device (causing the map to redraw) markers become invisible again.

I am using Samsung Galaxy p1000 with Android 2.2.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to remember there were a couple of errors in this tutorial.

Firstly the HelloItemizedOverlay constructor which takes a context needs to change to

```
public HelloItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, Context context) {
    // super(defaultMarker); - REPLACE THIS WITH LINE BELOW
    super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
    mContext = context;
}
```

and the context needs to be passed in from the other class

```
HelloItemizedOverlay itemizedoverlay = new HelloItemizedOverlay(drawable, this);
```

You shouldn't need to use the 'getMarker' change you described.

Comment: It worked. Thanks. But I needed to use custom marker for every item, so i've changed  `createItem(int)` method to `protected OverlayItem createItem(final int i) {
  OverlayItem item = items.get(i);
  Drawable drawable = item.getMarker(0);

  if (drawable != null) {
   int w = drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
   int h = drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();

   drawable.setBounds(0, 0, w, h);

   item.setMarker(drawable);
  }

  return item;
 }`